# bug on sending request to node js api from react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, axios

I have the following component to handle reservation payment confirmation (just confirmation not actual payment):

```
const CreditPayment = ({
  isOpen,
  handlePopupClose,
  totalPrice,
  setAmountPaid,
  setChange,
  handleConfirmPayment,
  bookingInfo,
  clients,
  dateTime,
}) => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem("ag_app_shop_token");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { isDarkMode } = useContext(DarkModeContext);

  const handleConfirm = () => {
    let data = {
      managerId: bookingInfo.managerId,
      customer: bookingInfo.customer,
      professional: bookingInfo.professional,
      service: bookingInfo.service,
      product: bookingInfo.product,
      dateTime: new Date(),
      amount: bookingInfo.amount,
      method: "credit",
    };

let patchData = {
  managerId: bookingInfo.managerId,
  customer: bookingInfo.customer,
  professional: bookingInfo.professional,
  service: bookingInfo.service,
  product: bookingInfo.product,
  dateTime: new Date(),
  amount: bookingInfo.amount + bookingInfo.prevPaid,
  method: "credit",
  updatedAt: new Date(),
};

console.log(data);
console.log(patchData);

let paymentId = "";

const updatePayment = () => {
  apiProvider
    .patch(`payments/${bookingInfo.paymentId}`, JSON.stringify(patchData), {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: token,
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      const cuurentClient = clients.find(
        (client) => client._id === bookingInfo.customer
      );
      const updatedClientPayments =
        Number(cuurentClient.payments) +
        Number(bookingInfo.amount) +
        Number(bookingInfo.prevPaid);
      apiProvider
        .patch(
          `customers/${bookingInfo.customer}`,
          JSON.stringify({ payments: updatedClientPayments }),
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Authorization: token,
            },
          }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          confirmAppointmentPayment();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          deletePayment();
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.message);
    });
};

const makePayment = () => {
  apiProvider
    .post("payments", JSON.stringify(data), {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: token,
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      paymentId = response.data.payment._id;
      const cuurentClient = clients.find(
        (client) => client._id === bookingInfo.customer
      );
      const updatedClientPayments =
        Number(cuurentClient.payments) + Number(bookingInfo.amount);
      apiProvider
        .patch(
          `customers/${bookingInfo.customer}`,
          JSON.stringify({ payments: updatedClientPayments }),
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
              Authorization: token,
            },
          }
        )
        .then((response) => {
          linkPaymentToAppointment();
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          deletePayment();
        });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.message);
    });
};

const deletePayment = () => {
  apiProvider
    .delete(`payments/${bookingInfo.paymentId}`, {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: token,
      },
    })
    .then((response) => {
      navigate("/checkout-appointments");
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.message);
    });
};

const linkPaymentToAppointment = () => {
  apiProvider
    .patch(
      `payments/${paymentId}`,
      JSON.stringify({ appointment: bookingInfo.appointmentId }),
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: token,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      confirmAppointmentPayment();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.message);
      deletePayment();
    });
};

const confirmAppointmentPayment = () => {
  apiProvider
    .patch(
      `appointments/${bookingInfo.appointmentId}`,
      JSON.stringify({
        service: bookingInfo.service,
        product: bookingInfo.product,
        status: "confirmed",
      }),
      {
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: token,
        },
      }
    )
    .then((response) => {
      setAmountPaid(totalPrice);
      setChange(0);

      handleConfirmPayment();
      handlePopupClose();
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error.message);
      deletePayment();
    });
};

if (bookingInfo.checkoutType === "updating") {
  updatePayment();
} else {
  makePayment();
}
};
return(
   //jsx
 )

 export defalt CreditPayment;
```

and I have the backend model as follows:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const paymentSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    managerId: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Manager",
    },
    appointment: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Appointment",
      // required: true,
    },
    customer: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Customer",
      required: true,
    },
    professional: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "Professional",
      required: true,
    },
    service: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Service" }],
    product: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Product" }],
    amount: {
      type: Number,
      required: true,
    },
    method: {
      type: String,
      enum: ["cash", "credit"],
    },
    dateTime: {
      type: Date,
      required: true,
   },
    description: {
      type: String,
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
); 
module.exports = mongoose.model("Payment", paymentSchema);
```

and I have the controller function for creating payment:

```
const createPayment = async (req, res) => {
   try {
    const payment = new Payment(req.body);
    await payment.save();
    res.status(201).json({ message: "Payment created successfully", payment 
});
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(400).json({ error: err.message });
  }
};
```

axios config:

```
import axios from "axios";

const apiProvider = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_API,
  timeout: 55000,
});

// Add a request interceptor
apiProvider.interceptors.request.use(
  (config) => {

    return config;
  },
  (error) => {
    // Do something with request error
    console.error(error);
    return Promise.reject(error);
  }
);

// Add a response interceptor
apiProvider.interceptors.response.use(
  (response) => {
    // Do something with response data
    return response;
  },
  (error) => {
    // Do something with response error
    console.error(error);
    return Promise.reject(error.response);
  }
);


export default apiProvider
```

some times the request return 404 and rerender the page after the first request (payment post). if I resend the request, suddenly, it's working fine. I searched for a solution, but I couldn't find one.